# Sqlalchemy complex in_ clause with tuple in list of tuples

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find a way to cause SQLAlchemy to generate a query of the following form:

```
select * from t where (a,b) in ((a1,b1),(a2,b2));
```

Is this possible?

If not, any suggestions on a way to emulate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thanks to Hao Lian above, I came up with a functional if painful solution.

Assume that we have a declarative-style mapped class, `Clazz`, and a `list` of tuples of compound primary key values, `values`
(Edited to use a better (IMO) sql generation style):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text,bindparam
...
    def __gParams(self, f, vs, ts, bs):
        for j,v in enumerate(vs):
            key = f % (j+97)
            bs.append(bindparam(key, value=v, type_=ts[j]))
            yield ':%s' % key

    def __gRows(self, ts, values, bs):
        for i,vs in enumerate(values):
            f = '%%c%d' % i
            yield '(%s)' % ', '.join(self.__gParams(f, vs, ts, bs))

    def __gKeys(self, k, ts):
        for c in k:  
            ts.append(c.type)
            yield str(c)

    def __makeSql(self,Clazz, values):
        t = []
        b = []
        return text(
                '(%s) in (%s)' % (
                    ', '.join(self.__gKeys(Clazz.__table__.primary_key,t)),
                    ', '.join(self.__gRows(t,values,b))),
                bindparams=b)
```

This solution works for compound or simple primary keys.  It's probably marginally slower than the `col.in_(keys)` for simple primary keys though.

I'm still interested in suggestions of better ways to do this, but this way is working for now and performs noticeably better than the `or_(and_(conditions))` way, or the `for key in keys: do_stuff(q.get(key))` way.

Answer (score 31):

Use `tuple_`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import tuple_

keys = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2)]
session.query(T).filter(tuple_(T.a, T.b).in_(keys)).all()
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_

Comment: Warning

Warning(from sqlalchemy doc):The composite IN construct is not supported by all backends, and is currently known to work on PostgreSQL and MySQL, but not SQLite. Unsupported backends will raise a subclass of DBAPIError when such an expression is invoked.

Comment: Anyone want to comment what the terminal `.all()` does?

Comment: @johnDanger, .all() returns all entries mathing filter conditions. Alternatively, you can call .first() to return the first result. There are other functions too. You can see query API here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html

Comment: will this also work with some null values on both sides in the database and in the provided tuple? e.g, [(1, '', 3), ('', 2, 1), (3, 3, 3), (1, 3, '')

Answer (score 2):

see the [tuple_ construct](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/expressions.html?highlight=tuple#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) in SQLAlchemy 0.6

Answer (score 0):

Simple painless approach with text clause:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

keys  = [('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2')]
statement = text(f'SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE (t.a, t.b) in :keys')
session.execute(statement, {'keys': tuple(keys)})
```

Just required to be sure that keys is the array of tuple pairs.