# How to properly bind pairs (array of tuples, multidimensional array) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, sqlalchemy, tuples

How to construct a mysql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (key->>"$.k1", key->>"$.k2") IN ((1, "string1"), (2, "string2"))
```

with SQLAlchemy?

I tried to use `text` but with no luck:

```
select([table.c.value]).where(
    text('(key->>"$.k1", key->>"$.k2") IN :pairs)').bindparams(
        pairs=[(1, "string1"), (2, "string2")]
    )
)
```

This code produced:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (key->>"$.k1", key->>"$.k2") IN NULL
```

Comment: Ignoring the `->>` operator, you'll find the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140015/how-to-get-rows-which-match-a-list-of-3-tuples-conditions-with-sqlalchemy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948212/sqlalchemy-complex-in-clause-with-tuple-in-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 1):

[Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4), thanks!

The following code works:

```
select([table.c.value]).where(
    tuple_(
        text('key->>"$.k1"'),
        text('key->>"$.k2"'),
    ).in_([[1, 'string1'], [2, 'string']])
)
```